Audio Input not working
After installing Ubuntu, "Headphone Stereo Microphone sof-hda-dsp" and "Digital Microphone sof-hda-dsp" are displayed under

--> Sound --> Input <-- in the selection.

I don't have a headphone connected to the laptop. Not even via Bluetooth.
None of the selections work. When you select the latter, you only hear a whistle.
What can I do?
Here is the output from

lspci


lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4601 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 04)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 04)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 04)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 04)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (16) I219-LM (rev 01)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 000c
58:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)


